# Complex sort order in VS Code Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to display the folders in my Workspace by Date Modified, but the files inside the folders by Filename.

Using the settings I can one or the other, but not both.

Is there an existing way to achieve this? If not; are there any recommendations on how to create an extension to do this?

Note: I am not allowed to use 3rd party extensions on my work computer, so I have to roll my own.

Thanks